# How do I make a function to get the entire list of users with all details like adress,userId,f name,l name,email id,private key that are registered

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How do I make a function to get the entire list of users with all details like wallet address,user Id,first name,last name,email id,private key  that are registered on my dapp from the ethereum blockchain?

struct User  {

```
    address  wallet_address;  
    string  userId;
    string  first_name;
    string  last_name;
    string  email_id;
    bool set;
    string private_key;

  }
 

  mapping(address => User)  users; 
  mapping(string => address) walletAccount;
  mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
  address[] public registeredArray;
  
  
  User public newUser ;
 
  uint public length;
  address public owner;
  
  
  constructor() public{
      
      owner = msg.sender;
  }
  
 

 

  function createNewUser(address userAcc,string memory _id,string memory firstName,string memory lastName,string memory emailId,string memory _private_key) public  {


      
     
      
      User storage user = users[userAcc];
      
      
     
     users[userAcc] = User(userAcc,_id,firstName,lastName,emailId,true,_private_key); 
      
      walletAccount[emailId] = userAcc;
      
      
     
  }


 
  
 
  
  function getUser(address _userAddress,string memory _emailId) public view returns(address,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory){
      
       User memory user = users[_userAddress];
       
       
      
        
       return(users[_userAddress].wallet_address,users[_userAddress].userId,users[_userAddress].first_name,users[_userAddress].last_name,users[_userAddress].email_id,users[_userAddress].private_key);
         
  }
  
  
   
    function Listofuser()public view returns(address[] memory){
return registeredArray;
```

}
}

Please I need some help here.   How do I make a function to get the entire list of users with all details like wallet address,user Id,first name,last name,email id,private key  that are registered on my dapp from the ethereum blockchain?

Comment: function createNewUser(address userAcc,string memory _id,string memory firstName,string memory lastName,string memory emailId,string memory _private_key) public  {


          
         
          
          User storage user = users[userAcc];
          
          
         
         users[userAcc] = User(userAcc,_id,firstName,lastName,emailId,true,_private_key); 
          
          walletAccount[emailId] = userAcc;
          
           registeredArray.push(userAcc);
         
      }   I have already pushed the array in createnewuser function

Comment: registeredArray.push(userAcc); } I have already pushed the array in createnewuser function

Comment: Please [edit] instead of commenting to update.